# how to instantiate ViewModel In AndroidX?

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, android-jetpack, kotlin-android-extensions

I want to initialize ViewModel in Activity using androidx library

I have tried what documentation says but it is not working. the ".of" is not resolved.

```kotlin
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import com.example.myapplication.databinding.ActivityMainBinding`

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val binding: ActivityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(
            this, R.layout.activity_main)
        binding.setLifecycleOwner(this)

        var model = ViewModelProvider.of(this).get(SheduleViewModel::class.java)

    }
}
```

of is not resolved, maybe there are another way to do it in androidx

Comment: What is `this`? Is it an `AppCompatActivity` or `FragmentActivity`? Or is it an AndroidX `Fragment`? Or is it something else?

Comment: You need to import `ViewModelProviders` to find `of`

Comment: it appCompatActivity, I can Import ViewModelProvider but it does not contain of method

Comment: Please give a **complete** code example. Show the surrounding class and appropriate imports. Also, copy-paste the **exact** error message.

Comment: You'll need to use class `ViewModelProviders` in-spite of `ViewModelProvider`.

Comment: thank you brothers, I really appreciate it

Comment: Add this dependency into your build.gradle file: implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'

Answer (score 142, accepted):

**Updated answer:**

Things changed a little bit, as the previously needed dependency - `ViewModelProviders` - [got deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProviders.html) (see the old answer for details). You can now use the `ViewModelProvider` constructor directly.

So, in this case, the answer would be:

```
private val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(SheduleViewModel::class.java)
```

Note that, however, if you include the `androidx.activity:activity-ktx:$Version` dependency (a few of the commonly used AndroidX dependencies already include it for you), you can make use of property delegation:

```
private val viewModel: SheduleViewModel by viewModels()
```

Which internally will use `ViewModelProvider` and scope your `ViewModel` to your `Activity`. It's just a more concise way of writing the same thing. You can do the same for a `Fragment` by including the `androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:$Version` dependency instead (again, commonly already included by other AndroidX dependencies).

Both the `ViewModelProvider` constructor and `by viewModels()` also accept a factory as a parameter (useful for injecting your `ViewModel`):

```
private val viewModel = 
    ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory).get(SheduleViewModel::class.java)
```

and

```
private val viewModel: SheduleViewModel by viewModels { viewModelFactory }
```

Use the one that best suits you.

**Old answer:**

Add the `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycleExtensionsVersion` dependency in order to import `ViewModelProviders`.

Comment: I imported viewmodelProviders. I can see it

Comment: If your code is per your edit, you're missing `import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders`. It has an **s** at the end. You need both `import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders` and `import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider`.

Comment: `ViewModelProviders` is deprecated, migrate to `ViewModelProvider`

Comment: Can you give the syntax in Java

Comment: @Siva it's pretty much the same thing: `SheduleViewModel viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(SheduleViewModel.class);`

Answer (score 21):

## Updating ViewModel to [Lifecycle Version 2.2.0](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#version_220_3) and Above

The *ViewModels* (VMs) may theoretically be initialized as class level instance variables using the Kotlin extension library `import androidx.fragment.app.viewModels` method `by viewmodels()`. By initializing the VM as a class level instance var it can be accessed within the class.

**Question: Is there a downside to initializing the VMs as class level instance variables instead of inside `onCreate`?**

When creating the VMs with the extension function inside `onCreate` the VMs are only scoped within `onCreate` and extra code is required to reassign the class level instance variables.

*See documentation*

- [ViewModel Overview](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel?utm_campaign=android_series_viewmodeldoc_110817&utm_source=anddev&utm_medium=yt-desc)
- [Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#declaring_dependencies)

## Initialize VM as Class Instance Val

```
class Fragment : Fragment() {
    private val viewModel: SomeViewModel by viewModels()

    private fun observeViewState() {
        viewModel.feedViewState.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { viewState ->
            //viewState used here.
        }
    }
}
```

## Initialize VM in onCreate and Reassign Class Instance Var

```
class Fragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var viewModel: SomeViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val viewModel: ContentViewModel by viewModels()
        this.viewModel = viewModel
    }

    private fun observeViewState() {
        viewModel.feedViewState.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { viewState ->
            //viewState used here.
        }
    }
}
```

## Passing Arguments/Parameters

```
// Override ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory to create the ViewModel (VM).
class SomeViewModelFactory(private val someString: String): ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory() {
    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T = SomeViewModel(someString) as T
} 

class SomeViewModel(private val someString: String) : ViewModel() {
    init {
        //TODO: Use 'someString' to init process when VM is created. i.e. Get data request.
    }
}

class Fragment: Fragment() {
    // Create VM in activity/fragment with VM factory.
    val someViewModel: SomeViewModel by viewModels { SomeViewModelFactory("someString") } 
}
```

## Enabling SavedState with Arguments/Parameters

```
class SomeViewModelFactory(
        private val owner: SavedStateRegistryOwner,
        private val someString: String) : AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory(owner, null) {
    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(key: String, modelClass: Class<T>, state: SavedStateHandle) =
            SomeViewModel(state, someString) as T
}

class SomeViewModel(private val state: SavedStateHandle, private val someString: String) : ViewModel() {
    val feedPosition = state.get<Int>(FEED_POSITION_KEY).let { position ->
        if (position == null) 0 else position
    }

    init {
        //TODO: Use 'someString' to init process when VM is created. i.e. Get data request.
    }

     fun saveFeedPosition(position: Int) {
        state.set(FEED_POSITION_KEY, position)
    }
}

class Fragment: Fragment() {
    // Create VM in activity/fragment with VM factory.
    val someViewModel: SomeViewModel by viewModels { SomeViewModelFactory(this, "someString") } 
    private var feedPosition: Int = 0

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        someViewModel.saveFeedPosition((contentRecyclerView.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager)
                .findFirstVisibleItemPosition())
    }    

    override fun onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState)
        feedPosition = someViewModel.feedPosition
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

For me, the only thing that worked:

```
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.2.4'
```

Answer (score 7):

PS. This is for someone who is using java and got stuck for a while like I did and this SO answer comes up in google all the time.

Apparently, the API has change as of this date (6 May 2020), I had to do this to get it working.

```
// 1. Create a ViewModel Class Let's call it AppStateViewModel

// 2. Put below code Inside Activity onCreate like this:
ViewModelProvider.Factory factory = new ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory();
appStateManager = new ViewModelProvider(this, factory).get(AppStateViewModel.class);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's what i was missing and most of the answers above would have taken even more time to falsify. If you are using up to date dependencies, this is probably your answer. The documentation https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata has not been updated to track the api change at the time of this comment

Comment: Thank you so much. This was what I was looking for and I couldn't find it anywhere. It was all kotlin or deprecated

Answer (score 6):

In your app gradle file make sure you have added below dependencies:

For Activity use:

```
implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.4.1"
```

For Fragment use:

```
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.4.1'
```

Answer (score 5):

> [ViewModelProviders](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProviders):  This class is deprecated. Use the constructors for ViewModelProvider directly.

Examples in **Kotlin**

This is how you can use [ViewModelProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProvider) directly:

If your view-model is extending **[AndroidViewModel](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/AndroidViewModel)** with just one argument, the app - then you can use the default [AndroidViewModelFactory](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory) and you don't have to write a new Factory. Example:

```
// Activity / fragment class
private lateinit var viewModel: MyOwnAndroidViewModel

    // onCreate
    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(
            this,
            ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory(application)
        ).get(MyOwnAndroidViewModel::class.java)
```

If your view-model is only extending the **[ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModel)** without extra arguments then use the [NewInstanceFactory()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory).

```
// Activity / fragment class
private lateinit var viewModel: MyOwnViewModel

    // onCreate
    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(
            this,
            ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory()
        ).get(MyOwnViewModel::class.java)
```

*Adam's answer above covers other variations as well.*

*Disclaimer: Still learning basic Android development - if there's any problem with the code, let me know in comments.*

Comment: For some reason I was asked to use [MyOwnViewModel::class.java] instead of .get(MyOwnViewModel::class.java)

Answer (score 4):

*(How to)* Use `ViewModel` from **Android Architecture Component** :

1. **Add the Google Maven repository (Optional, just verify that)**

   Android Studio projects aren't configured to access this repository by default.

   To add it to your project, open the `build.gradle` file for your project *(not the ones for your app or module)* and add the **`google()`** repository as shown below:

   ```
   allprojects {
       repositories {
           google()
           jcenter()
       }
   }
   ```
2. **Declaring dependencies**

   Open your app-level `build.gradle` file,

   Go to **`dependencies{}`** block

   Put `implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:$lifecycle_version"` for **AndroidX** version, **$lifecycle_version** here is latest version defined.

   **For Pre-AndroidX** use `implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.1"` *(1.1.1 is the last version from this artifact i guess.)*
3. **In your activity, use like this syntax**

   Import this class :

   `import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;` for **AndroidX**

   `import android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;` when using **Pre-AndroidX**

   And obtain your `ViewModel` like following

   `ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ProfileObservableViewModel::class.java)` // Kotlin syntax

   ---- or ----

   `ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ProfileObservableViewModel.class);` // Java syntax

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: `ViewModelProviders` is in extensions, see Ricardo Costeira's answer.

Answer (score 4):

---

Paste the code below in build.gradle(:app)

```
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.4.1'
```

Answer (score 1):

paste the following or similar(relevant to your settings) in app.gradle under dependencies

```
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5'
```

Answer (score 1):

I add the last version of this dependency from
https://developer.android.com/kotlin/ktx/extensions-list

implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.4.0"