# As ViewModelProviders.of() is deprecated, how should I create object of ViewModel?

Tags: android, viewmodel

I have been trying to create an Object of ViewModel in an Activity but ViewModelProviders is deprecated So what's the alternative to create the ViewModel's object.

Answer (score 161):

Simply replace:

This:

```
boardViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(BoardViewModel::class.java)
```

With this:

```
boardViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(BoardViewModel::class.java)
```

Comment: In Java: "boardViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(BoardViewModel.class)"

Comment: boardViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get("model", BoardViewModel::class.java) only compile for me in latest versions.

Comment: For me .get(UserViewModel::class.java) has red underline that is for some reason saying " Type parameter bound for T in 

operator fun <T : ViewModel!> get
(
modelClass: Class<T!>
)
: T
is not satisfied: inferred type UserViewModel! is not a subtype of ViewModel! ".

Comment: What does **this** stand for?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky The UI controller (activity or fragment) you want to tie to the viewmodel.

Answer (score 54):

This Gradle upgrade created the problem for me.

FROM

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.1.0'
```

TO

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.2.0'
```

IN MAIN ACTIVITY Java/Kotlin Files

This import statement

```
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders
```

had to be changed to

```
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
```

This KOTLIN viewModel statement

```
viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainActivityViewModel::class.java)
```

had to be changed to

```
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainActivityViewModel::class.java)
```

and in JAVA

This line of JAVA code

```
mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainActivityViewModel.class);
```

had to be changed to

```
mViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainActivityViewModel.class);
```

and then it all worked for me.

Based on:
An outline of the steps that created the problem for me
[image]

Comment: this is. by far the most clear and the best answer.

Comment: yeah man! the best solution was this, it really solved my problem here.

Comment: Hey, what about AndroidViewModel which needs Application as constructor argument?

Answer (score 35):

> ViewModelProviders.of() has been deprecated.
>   [image]

Use ViewModelProvider constructors directly as they now handle the default ViewModelProvider.Factory role.

> Java

```
 mainActivityViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainActivityViewModel.class);
```

> Kotlin

```
mainActivityViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainActivityViewModel::class.java)
```

Comment: This did the trick in my case. Thanks! It's just nice to mention that I had to change some reded `this` to `getViewLifecycleOwner()` to avoid warnings.

Answer (score 14):

Instead of `ViewModelProviders` we should now use `ViewModelProvider` constructors and it has three:

```
public ViewModelProvider(ViewModelStoreOwner owner)
public ViewModelProvider(ViewModelStoreOwner owner, Factory factory)
public ViewModelProvider(ViewModelStore store, Factory factory)
```

**1.** If you are not using a `ViewModelProvider.Factory` to [pass additional arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46283981/android-viewmodel-additional-arguments) to your `ViewModel`, you can use the first one. so:

```
viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(YourViewModel.class);
```

can be replaced with:

```
viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(YourViewModel.class);
```

`AppCompatActivity` and different kinds of `Fragment`s are indirect subclasses of `ViewModelStoreOwner` (see the complete list of its known subclasses [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelStoreOwner#getViewModelStore())), so you can use them in this constructor.

**2.** But if you are using a `ViewModelProvider.Factory`, you should use the second or the third constructors:

```
viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(YourViewModel.class);
```

can be replaced with:

```
viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory).get(YouViewModel.class);
```

OR based on the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelStore) of `ViewModelStore`:

> Use ViewModelStoreOwner.getViewModelStore() to retrieve a
>   ViewModelStore for activities and fragments.

```
viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(getViewModelStore(), viewModelFactory).get(YourViewModel.class);
```

Comment: this is the best ans

Answer (score 10):

If you're using Kotlin, instead of:

```
private lateinit var viewModel: EntityGridViewModel

[...]

// Deprecated
viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(EntityGridViewModel::class.java)
```

You can use the nicer:

```
private val viewModel: EntityGridViewModel by viewModels()
```

Comment: The question is about alternative to what you've proposed

Comment: how can i pass a factory to the 'viewModels()' delegate ???

Answer (score 9):

ViewModelProviders.of() has been deprecated. You can pass a Fragment or FragmentActivity to the new ViewModelProvider(ViewModelStoreOwner) constructor to achieve the same functionality. (aosp/1009889)

[Please click here to see the solution](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#2.2.0-alpha03)

Answer (score 9):

For `java`:

Simply replace this:

```
viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(YOUR_VIEW_MODEL::class.java)
```

With this:

`viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(YOUR_VIEW_MODEL::class.java)`

if you are having your own factory then,

```
viewModel = 
ViewModelProvider(this,YOUR_FACTORY).get(YOUR_VIEW_MODEL::class.java)
```

For `kotlin`:
There is a nicer way to do this. you can add the below dependencies in app `build.gradle`:

```
//for activity
implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.3.0-alpha06"
//for fragment
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.2"
```

and then access the viewmodel like below:

```
private val viewmodel: YOUR_VIEW_MODEL by viewModels()
```

If you have your own view model factory then,

```
  private val viewmodel: YOUR_VIEW_MODEL by viewModels { YOUR_VIEW_MODEL_FACTORY }
```

Answer (score 7):

The simple option for the next several months is to stick with stable or beta versions. `ViewModelProviders` is only deprecated starting with `2.2.0`, presently in an `alpha03` release.

For when you do move to `2.2.0` or higher of the lifecycle dependencies, your options depend on your language:

- If you are using Java, use the `ViewModelProvider()` constructor, passing in your activity or fragment
- If you are using Kotlin, there is supposed to be a `by viewModels()` property delegate, though I am not finding it in the source code...

Comment: to use `by viewModels()` you need to add this dependency `implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.0'`

Comment: @CommonsWare
I guess we should use below dependencies to instantiate view model


For Fragments
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:x.x.x'


For Activities
implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:x.x.x"

Comment: @VikashKumarTiwari: Yes, I believe that `by viewModels()` and `by activityViewModels()` are defined in the `fragment-ktx` and `activity-ktx` artifacts.

Comment: @CommonsWare As per latest release
Version 1.2.0
January 22, 2020

by viewModels() and  by activityViewModels() are present in below dependency
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.0'

Also, by viewModels() is to be used for viewmodel initialization in both activity and fragment.

But by activityViewModels() can only be used in fragment to get parent activity's viewmodel.

Moreover, while using implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:x.x.x" 
We can access by viewModels() only in activity and it will not be accessed in fragment.

Answer (score 5):

This code works for me

```
private lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory()).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
```

Answer (score 4):

lifecycle-extensions 2.2.0 version:

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"
```

ViewModelProvider with constructor uses

```
 // With ViewModelFactory   
 val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, YourViewModelFactory).get(YourViewModel::class.java)


//Without ViewModelFactory
val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(YourViewModel::class.java)
```

Answer (score 2):

> This class is deprecated. 
>   Use the constructors for ViewModelProvider directly. 
>   [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProviders)

**So instead of using this**

```
ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel.class); - deprecated
```

**Use this one**

```
new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel.class); - correct
```

Answer (score 2):

As **ViewModelProviders** got deprecated. You can now use the **ViewModelProvider** constructor directly. For more details how to use it, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54313573/5954565).

Answer (score 0):

you can add the below dependencies in app `build.gradle`:

```
//for activity
implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.2.2"
//for fragment
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.2"
```

and then use like below:

```
private val viewmodel: YOUR_VIEW_MODEL_CLASS_NAME by viewModels()
```

If you have your own view model factory then,

```
  private val viewmodel: YOUR_VIEW_MODEL_CLASS_NAME by viewModels { YOUR_VIEW_MODEL_FACTORY }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private lateinit var vm: SRViewModel
private lateinit var adapter: StudentRecordsAdapter
```

Deprecated

```
vm = ViewModelProviders.of(this)[SRViewModel::class.java]
```

Use this line of code

```
vm=  ViewModelProvider(this)[SRViewModel::class.java]
```