# How to get an Instance of ViewModel in activity in 2020/21?

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel, androidx, viewmodelproviders

I am new to the mvvm pattern. I created a ViewModel for the main activity. Now I want to get an instance of the ViewModel in the main activity.

Most Tutorials and answers here on Stackoverflow suggest using `ViewModelProviders.of(...`, but this is depreceated.

So according to this question on stackoverflow: [ViewModelProviders is deprecated in 1.1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53903762/viewmodelproviders-is-deprecated-in-1-1-0,in) main activity in onCreate, I do the following (and I could swear I already had it running): `mainActivityViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainActivityViewModel.class);`

However, I am getting an error telling me, that no suitable constructor has been found.

`error: no suitable constructor found for ViewModelProvider(MainActivity)`

Alternatively to make absolutely clear, that the MainActivity shall be the ViewModelStoreOwner, I created a variable 
`ViewModelStoreOwner vmso = this;` and put that variable into the constructor like so: 
`mainActivityViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(vmso).get(MainActivityViewModel.class);`

Comment: are you sure your reference to `this` is correct? If it's a Fragment you'll need to use `getActivity()` instead of `this` iirc, and if you are in a listener or anonymous class you will have to do `MainActivity@this` etc etc

Comment: I am calling the method in onCreate() of the main activity

Comment: Does this answer your question? [As ViewModelProviders.of() is deprecated, How should i create object of ViewModel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57534730/as-viewmodelproviders-of-is-deprecated-how-should-i-create-object-of-viewmode)

Comment: No, it doesn not. The described solution in Java code is ```boardViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(BoardViewModel.class)```, which is equivalent to  ```mainActivityViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainActivityViewModel.class);``` which I already tried, but seems to be no suitable constructor.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You should update your gradle file to:

> implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'

And due to this change you can pass Activity to the constructor you mentioned:

```
mainActivityViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainActivityViewModel.class);
```

Answer (score 18):

Using [Fragment-ktx](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/ktx) libr in your app you can get viewModel as below

### First Update Gradle File as app -> build.gradle

```
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.1.0'
```

// get **ViewModel** in **Activity** or **Fragment** as

```
private val viewModel: MainActivityViewModel by viewModels()
```

// If you want to get same instance of **ViewModel** in **ChildFragment** as

```
 private val viewModel: MainActivityViewModel by viewModels(
    ownerProducer = { requireParentFragment() }
)
```

Comment: Fragment-ktx is for fragments.  We need **activity-ktx**

Comment: And what if Activity is derived from `androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity` and NOT the `androidx.activity.ComponentActivity`?

Answer (score 18):

Based on [Android](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#implement) documentation, you can do this:

KOTLIN

```
implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.3.1'

val model: MyViewModel by viewModels()
```

---

JAVA

```
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0'

MyViewModel model = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel.class);
```

Answer (score 17):

Use `val viewModel by viewModels<TheViewModel>()` in Activities and `val viewModel by activityViewModels<TheViewModel>()` in fragment to obtain the same viewmodel from the activity (so sharing the viewmodel).

This is part of `androidx` now

Comment: Thanks! This is probably obvious to most people, but you can also do `val viewModel: ThisViewModel by viewModels()` and `val viewModel: ThisViewModel by activityViewModels()`

Answer (score 6):

**Get ViewModel In New Way**

```
MainActivityViewModel mainActivityViewModel;
    mainActivityViewModel= new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainActivityViewModel.class);
```

Comment: This is Java.  We use Kotlin.

Answer (score 2):

For now, the only thing working for me was to use:
`MainActivityViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this, new ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory()).get(MainActivityViewModel.class);`

However, I am still thankful for any advice, how this can be done different using `new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainActivityViewModel.class);`

Comment: This still fails, but this time with `java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class xxx` instead

Comment: Did you follow the first answer ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `ViewModelFactory`:

```
val viewModelFactory = VMFactory(requireActivity().application)
viewModel= ViewModelProvider(requireActivity(),viewModelFactory).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
```

VMFactory code:

```
class VMFactory(application: Application) : ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory() {

    val _application: Application=application

    @NonNull
    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(@NonNull modelClass: Class<T>): T {
            return  MainViewModel(_application) as T
    }
}
```

Please note that here my `MainViewModel` extends `AndroidViewModel` and hence requires application as the input parameter.

Answer (score 0):

[Duplicate question and already answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57534730/as-viewmodelproviders-of-is-deprecated-how-should-i-create-object-of-viewmode)

Simply replace:

This:

```
boardViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(BoardViewModel::class.java)
```

With this:

```
boardViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(BoardViewModel::class.java)
```

Comment: If this question is a duplicate, please refrain from answering and flag as so instead

Comment: Plus, your suggestion does not work but fails with `error: no suitable constructor found for ViewModelProvider(MainActivity)` as described in the question

Comment: main thing to notice here is the line that we need to replace is ViewModelProvider not ViewModelProviders. notice the 's' here at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems and in the end found out I missed off the "***extends ViewModel***" within the class definition, so it should look like this:

```
public class ViewModelClass extends ViewModel
{
    // Tracks the score for Team A
    public int scoreTeamA = 0;

    // Tracks the score for Team B
    public int scoreTeamB = 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

ViewModel viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ViewModel.class);

Android Support library version is depreciated. So you need to make sure that you import Androidx. And you need to implement androidx dependency in Gradle file.

It is not advised to create a new ViewModel object with "new" keyword.

Comment: According to the developer guides, ViewModelProviders is depreceated and it is recommended to use the constructors directly.

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProviders.html