# Could Not use ViewModelProvider in androidx JAVA

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-room, lifecycle

This question might look like an duplicate question but those questions didn't help me : (

Im using Java, AndroidX and Android Studio 3.6

I am trying to implement Room Database with LiveData, ViewModel and Lifecycle

But When I am initializing MyViewModelClass using **`ViewModelProviders.of(this).get()`**

I am Getting **"Cannot resolve method get()"** error [Image Of the Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DEgD.jpg)

So I searched on google and found to use another alternative class **`ViewModelProvider`**

But I can't even **Import** this class

While Importing I get **"Cannot resolve symbol ViewModelProvider"** [[Image Of the Error]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hD9nF.jpg)

My Gradle dependencies for lifecycle and room are

```
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.4.2'
    annotationProcessor 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.2'

    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.6.2'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.6.2'
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.6.2'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.6.2'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.6.2'
```

I tried Changing the Dependecy versions, creating new project

I don't understand what the problem is

If I made any mistake in implementing ***Please*** let me know

Thanks in advance : )

Comment: You can do ViewmodelProvider(this) instead or use viewModels(). Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54313573/4545369

Comment: @StarterPack But ViewModelProvider() is not even being imported it is showing error "Cannot resolve symbol ViewModelProider" and to the next part I don't know how to use viewModels() in java

Answer (score 0):

As per official doc https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModelProviders `ViewModelProviders.of()` method is deprecated.
Please refer https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProviders

> For **Java**

```
// replace
viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainActivityViewModel.class);

// with
vewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainActivityViewModel.class);
```

> For **kotlin** reference

```
// replace 
viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainActivityViewModel::class.java)

// with
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainActivityViewModel::class.java)
```

if you use kotlin you have one advantage of **Lazy Initialization**

```
private val viewModel: MainActivityViewModel by viewModels()
```